# How to detect what was responsible for a peak in active oracle sessions?

Tags: database, oracle, oracle10g

We had problems with our Oracle 10g DB which reached the CPU Usage limit. (It's a Java Web application using Hibernate as Persistance Framework, JDBC and a c3p0 Connection Pooling)

In our monitoring we can see that there is a strong correlation between the cpu usage and the active sessions. 
There is a single peak to around 75 active session (the active seesion are usually around 10) wich is probably responsible for the trouble we run into.

My question is, how can I find out what was responsible for this peak in active sessions?
Is it possible that a crawler could cause this peak?

[Edit]
We analyzed access log and found out that there is no traffic peak during that speficic time-intervall, in which the active session peaks occured.
I suppose it is a consequence of the high CPU, wich leaded to extremly long DB query durations. But it's only an assumption. 
Maybe someone has any hints or further explanation?

Thanks in advance for any hints and advice.
Ronny

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can verify whether a crawler caused the peak by analyzing the web server log:

- Can you see an unusally high number of requests during the peak time?
- Does the agent identification include words like *bot*, *spider* or *crawler*?

Comment: Thanks for that hint. Anyway we analyzed our accesslogs and couldn't see neitherunusual bot activity during that time nor any traffic peak at all.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle Enterprise Manager can give you a good view into what is happening in Oracle.  It takes periodic snapshots, and you can examine what is running at that point, and what sorts of states the processes are in at that time.